# Setting up Twilio client

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, methods, twilio, rake-task

I'm accessing the Twilio API to send out daily messages to all users in my database. The message should be the same for everyone and is coming from an array of messages I've put together. I'm using the Heroku Scheduler to trigger a rake task I built that will run the task at a certain hour every day. However, because of how my Twilio client model is set up, a new instance of the model is created every time the task is run, therefore always sending the first message in the array (rather than going through the array consecutively as it's set up to do). Does anyone know of a way to rearrange or recode my model or rake task so this doesn't happen? It should ideally run itself.

twilio_client.rb model:

```
 class TwilioClient
    require 'twilio-ruby'

    def initialize
        @client = Twilio::REST::Client.new ENV["TWILIO_ACCOUNT_SID"], ENV["TWILIO_AUTH_TOKEN"]
        @index = 0
    end

    def notify
        all_phone_numbers.each do |number|
            @client.account.messages.create(
                from: '+1401XXXXXXX',
                to: number,
                body: daily_text
            )
        end
    end

    private

    def daily_text
        @message = [ 
            "1", "2", "3"
        ]

        @index += 1
        if @index >= @message.length
            @index = 0
        end

        @message[@index]
    end

    def all_phone_numbers
        User.pluck(:phone_number)
    end

end
```

rake task:

```
desc "This task is called by the Heroku scheduler add-on"
task notify: :environment do
  client = TwilioClient.new
  client.notify
end
```

Comment: Are you scheduling just one job or one for every user phone number?

Comment: @Matt Only one job. My notify method in the model above is iterating over my entire list of numbers.

Comment: Sounds like you would need to persist the value of index at the end of your iteration. Then in subsequent job runs look up the value to know where you left off. Even if you could get the scheduler to persist your task and do it in memory, if your server node gets cycled its going to lose its place and you'll flood your users with duplicate messages.